# Ensure a list of objects have unique keys in TypeScript at compile-time

Tags: typescript, recursion

I have a list of objects in TypeScript and I'd like to ensure that their keys are unique at **compile-time**.

For instance:

```js
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const obj2 = { c: 3, d: 4 };
const obj3 = { e: 5, f: 6 };
const obj4 = { a: 7, g: 8 }; // 'a' is duplicated
```

I'm able to write a TS function that ensures uniqueness between any two objects:

```js
declare function ensureUniqueKeys<
  A,
  B extends { [K in keyof B]: K extends keyof A ? never : B[K] },
>(a: A, b: B): unknown;

ensureUniqueKeys(obj1, obj2); // no issues
ensureUniqueKeys(obj1, obj4); // Error: Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
```

But I can't figure out a way to make this work with an arbitrary list of objects.

I've been trying to write some sort of recursive checker, but it never reports any error:

```js
type EnsureUniqueKeys<T extends string[], PreviousKeys = never> = T extends [
  infer First,
  ...infer Rest,
]
  ? First extends object
    ? Rest extends string[]
      ? keyof First extends PreviousKeys
        ? never // Overlap detected, trigger a compile-time error
        : EnsureUniqueKeys<Rest, PreviousKeys | keyof First>
      : never
    : never
  : unknown;

declare function ensureUniqueKeysRecursive<T extends string[]>(...objects: EnsureUniqueKeys<T>[]): unknown;

ensureUniqueKeysRecursive(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4); // No errors :(
```

Again: I'm aware that this could be done at run-time easily, but I need it to check uniqueness at **compile-time**.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXxFQGdk4BVVLAR2RAGkQBPIgHgCh54BBAGg-gBCBAB4ZCwIvADe8ANp14WfAGsmORIIC6ALngKQo8ZNWN13eAH54qEADcQMeLoHzN8AL58AfAAoou3ngAI2cASl00ZVQcAHdUAG42NjA8Igx4HCCAKwBGeABeaXh-eByeYN0AJg9ElOJ0zKzqwpkwXQBmcuBdABYa5NSG7PaCopBdAFZyxF0ANn66tIzsvpbi3QB2coBzXQAOGvgAeiP4AHIoM8VJYGQABwgsMCgxYCTCEnJKGnomIh9GmVlk1QokPqQQBRqLQGMwAdkgY12qC2OCvtDfnDAeVGj0UWwMIw7ggAKLECFQn6w1gAFREYlQEngaRgSm2sk05QACnBbLhkERqaMbPYYF5RnSDAymbJ+EpEA54AAxLAwNJ8TgAOm18sVACUQOq2Jp+FYVWr0lKjMDwBh+JwrAallbGZIWWyOfbOJZ4CYzObnYZXfAeXZ+YK-l7vT6RYqTvAAPKi6B3eCgMSYEDAcoYVnbbaKqDwFIAWzuWAgIAAtNgSwgHDAcDAo97dGTPpDvjC-iwnRhubzw0KAD6+tQaAMYLwt3Sx5vR2d2Bz8CKoKKxBJJUCQWAIFDobB4Ajk9FUv4GsCkIhYewsSVBpnu1DszS+bWaxq2ohtk+djHUu8vA5cJ4EiaI4kSVFf0pbtmAvK8bxAeFchxbJKlQrJOmBPF4iAA)

Comment: This impossible. There is no compile time guarantee that an object *only* has certain keys at runtime.

Comment: @JaredSmith have a look at the example - this works properly with any two objects, the challenge is to extend it to work with an arbitrary list of objects.

See my attempt at that, theoretically this should be possible, I just can't figure out why my example doesn't and what part is not working.

Comment: Your example is mistaken. *Again*, Typescript is structurally typed, there can always be extra properties. The compiler can only guarantee properties are unique that it knows about at compile time, but nothing prevents `obj3.a = 'whatever'` executing at runtime.

Comment: @JaredSmith that's exactly what I'm asking, I want to guarantee that the objects have unique keys at compile time. Whatever happens after this point is not a concern for the compiler.

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand why you are trying to do complicated type logic for something you can't guarantee. It's like having a bunker with 10 ft thick reinforced concrete walls and an unlocked front door. But whatever it's your code, you can do as you wish with it.

Comment: @JaredSmith I know, and I'm fully aware - explaining the why and the context is a bit complex and out of scope, but basically this is a nice-to-have validation check, coupled with strict eslint functional rules to ensure object immutability so even though you *can* mutate them later we're doing what we can to validate this at compile-time.

Comment: One can phrase this as the requirement that there are no keys *known* to appear in multiple objects I guess.  I’d love to look at this but I suspect someone else will get to it before I get to a real computer.  I doubt it needs recursion, probably just a one-level-nested mapped tuple type

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WvzQnW) meet your needs?  It does not need recursion.  If it works for you I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Okay I will write up an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The goal is to write `ensureUniqueKeys()` so that it accepts a variadic number of object arguments, so that no key of any of argument is known to exist in any other argument.

The approach I'd take is to make a [mapped type over the array of inputs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) `T`, iterating over the numberlike keys `I`.

For each element `T[I]`, we can construct the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of keys of every element of `T` *except* the one at index `I`.  We can map over `T` again, this time iterating over the numberlike keys `J`.  The set of keys we're looking for is `{ [J in keyof T]: J extends I ? never : keyof T[J] }[number]`.

If `T[I]` has any key `K` in that set of keys, then it's a duplicated key and will set the property to `never`.  Otherwise we will leave it as `T[I][K]`.

The whole thing looks like:

```
declare function ensureUniqueKeys<T extends object[] & {
  [I in keyof T]: {
    [K in keyof T[I]]: K extends {
      [J in keyof T]: J extends I ? never : keyof T[J]
    }[number] ? never : T[I][K]
  }
}>(...args: T): void;
```

Let's test it:

```
const obj1 = { a: 1, b: 2 };
const obj2 = { c: 3, d: 4 };
const obj3 = { e: 5, f: 6 };
const obj4 = { a: 7, g: 8 }; // 'a' is duplicated
ensureUniqueKeys(obj1, obj2, obj3); // okay
ensureUniqueKeys(obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4); // error
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// The types of 'a' are incompatible between these types.
```

Looks good.

---

For clarity, let's walk through the types a bit.

In the first call, `T` is inferred as `[{a: number, b: number}, {c: number, d: number}, {e: number, f: number}]`.  `I` iterates over the numberlike keys `"0"`, `"1"`, and `"2"`.  When `I` is `"0"`, then `{ [J in keyof T]: J extends I ? never : keyof T[J] }` is `[never, "c" | "d", "e" | "f"]`; the first element is `never` because `J extends I` is true there.  [Indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) this with `number` gives `"c" | "d" | "e" | "f"`.  Since `T[0]` has no keys in that set, then `{ [K in keyof T[0]]: K extends "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" ? never : T[0][K] }` is just `{a: number, b: number}`.  Meaning that the first element of `T` is acceptable because it's assignable to itself.  You can show that the other two elements are also acceptable.

In the second call, `T` is inferred as `[{a: number, b: number}, {c: number, d: number}, {e: number, f: number}, {a: number, g: number}]`.  Now when `I` is `"0"`, the type `{ [J in keyof T]: J extends I ? never : keyof T[J] }` is `[never, "c" | "d", "e" | "f", "a" | "g"]`, and indexing with `number` gives `"c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "a" | "g"]`.  Since `T[0]` does have a key in that set, then `{ [K in keyof T[0]]: K extends "c" | "d" | "e" | "f" | "a" | "g"  ? never : T[0][K] }` is equivalent to `{a: never, b: number}`.  That means the first element of `T` is *not* acceptable, because `{a: number, b: number}` is *not* assignable to `{a: never, b: number}`.  And we get an error message saying there's a problem with the `a` key.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAEwpgxgNghgTmABAMwK4DsIBcCWB7dRMdAZ1QQFV0cBHVMAaTAE8SAeAFSIA8tiQSiPACMAVpCwBtALqIAZIgDewRIkkBJRDkIBrFnmSIO0gFxKVqtQy279hjhumnE1sL36Dlly5IBSNxD1mAyNnfzc+dAFETQB+RHQwADcwOEQzIJCHX2kLVQBfSXRUAFthVNl4xJS0swd1aUkGXILgfIA+AAoAOl74AHMSOoBKMyS8HBAAbmBgCAISLCExAEZEAF4lRBgzFYAaRGEzACZEfJn50iWRUVPNxUQIMwBmA5AzABYzi4XrsWeNlswGYAKwHZBmABs3zmv2Woi+922ZgA7Ad+mYABzfRAAelxiAA5DBCVpBCBUAAHKA4CAwPggYDEMiUah0RgsEidG77eHHA43Z7DKZ4gl4HQwZhM0jkMBUWj0JisbmrAVifnw17wj7C0VEOBwPBwYD47xm80APyt1pttrtFpNBI4AAskFhmJSwIIQsTSfAkNp5iVKfScMIoEhylgAO5gYiILCukhuj1e7qzIA)

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! By the way, is there a good way to debug TS code like this? I feel like I probably could've reached a working solution but the compiler is so opaque that it's hard to know which part isn't working...